# Let U,W be subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$ that are not subspaces of each other. show that $U+W=\mathbb R^4$ if these two vectors exist in the intersection

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm kinda confused what I'm supposed to start with.
The question is :

We have 2 subspaces $U,W$ of $\mathbb R^4$. $W$ is not a subspace of $U$ and $U$ is not subspace of $W$.
Also, The vectors $(1,2,1,0),(0,0,1,3)$ exist in $W⋂U$.
show that $U+W=\mathbb R^4$.

So we know that the intersection of subspaces is also subspace so $(1,2,1,0)+(0,0,1,3)$
which equals to $(1,2,2,3)$ is also exist in the intersection.                                              And if it exists in the intersection it also exist in $U,W$.

And here I'm stuck,I don't know how to proceed with the question or if my direction was right.
I have no idea how to proceed.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: $\dim U$ and $\dim V$ are at least $2$ by the vectors given, but none of $\dim U$, $\dim V$ can be equal to $2$ (because the larger would include the narrower), so they are at least $3$ each. Now if $W^{\perp}\cap U^{\perp}\ne \{0\}$ one of them again should include an other, thus $(W+U)^{\perp}=\{0\}$ thus $U+W=\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: What can be the dimension of $W$ and of $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v_1=(1,2,1,0)$ and $v_2=(0,0,1,3)$ are linearly independent.

As $U \neq W$, it exists $v_3$ such that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent and $\mathrm{Span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is included in $U$. Similarly $v_4$ such that $v_1,v_2,v_4$ are linearly independent and $\mathrm{Span}\{v_1,v_2,v_4\}$ is included in $W$.

$\dim \mathrm{Span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}=3$ implies $v_4 \in \mathrm{Span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and $U=W$. Hence $\dim \mathrm{Span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}=4$ and $U+W=\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: I got everything that you wrote except the last row. dimSpan${v1,v2,v3,v4}$=3 implies that U=W (because it means one vector is lineary dependent if so - it means U is subspace of W and W is subspace of U but its contradicts our given information). so the span must be equal to 4 and then $U+W=R^4$ ?

Comment: See updated answer. $\dim \mathrm{Span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}=3$ implies $v_4 \in \mathrm{Span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

With the given  wording the result is false. Take $U$ to be the span of $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $W$ to be the span of $\{e_1,e_3\}$ for a counter-example. Note that $e_1$ and $2e_1$ are in $U \cap W$.

If $U \cap W$ contains two **linearly independent** vectors then the conclusion is true.

Hint. Let $x_1 \in U\setminus W$ and $y_1 \in W\setminus U$. Let $x,y$ be  linearly independent vectors in $U \cap W$. Verify that $x,y,x_1,y_1$ are linearly independent . All these are in $U+W$ and hence $U+W$ is four dimensional.

Comment: oh ok I got it , Thank you.